# llamar a funcion dentro de funcion en php

Tags: php, funciones

¿es posible llamar a la funcion prueba2 que esta dentro de la funcion prueba?

```
     <?php
     function prueba(){
         echo "hola";
        function prueba2(){
              echo "adios";
        }
      }
      prueba2();
      ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si se puede, nadamos que debes llamar primero el método "principal" o "padre" para que el segundo método se ejecute, en tu ejemplo, tienes el código así:

```
<?php

function prueba(){
  echo "Hola prueba1 <br />";

  function prueba2(){
    echo "Hola prueba 2 <br />";
  }
}

prueba();
prueba2();
```

Si no ejecutas el primer método, el segundo jamás existirá. Ya que prueba2 depende completamente de prueba. Te dejo el [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php) de la documentación de PHP para que puedas comprender mejor el tema.

Comment: gracias por ayudarme.